# Installing iCub (Humanid) simulator on Linux mint 17

Tags: linux-mint

Can anybody tell me the procedure for installing iCub (humanoid) simulator on Linux mint 17 operating system. It seems they have only got the instruction procedure for Linux version of Debian and Ubuntu on their website.

Thanks
Lekan

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint 17 is derived from Ubuntu 14.04. So you can use the same installation procedure for the Ubuntu to Linux Mint. Steps for the same are given below.

1. Open terminal and enter the following command.

   **sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://www.icub.org/ubuntu trusty contrib/science" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/icub.list'**

   **sudo apt-get update**

   **sudo apt-get install icub**

For more information follow the link [iCub Installation procedure for Linux](http://wiki.icub.org/wiki/Linux:Installation_from_binaries)